# form action con parámetro no dispara modulo mediante url

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, express

Tengo este formulario:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" role="search" action="/quizes?search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Esta ruta:

```
router.get('/quizes?search', quizController.search);
```

Debería disparar éste módulo:

```
exports.search = function(req, res, next) {
    models.Quiz.findAll({
        where: {
            id: req.params.search,
            centro: req.session.user.centro
        },
        order: [['id', 'ASC']]
    }).then( quizes => {
        console.log('search...:' + req.params.search);
        res.render('quizes/index.ejs', {quizes: quizes, errors: []});
    }).catch( error => {
        next(error);
    });
};
```

Es curioso porque ni siquiera muestra en consola el texto del `log`, sin embargo sí renderiza la vista `index.ejs`.

No sé qué puede ser porque es sencillo este cógido.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que estás parseando mal la ruta GET.

Tu router tienes

```
router.get('/quizes?search', quizController.search);
```

Esto significa que va a responder para esa ruta exacta, es decir '/quizes?search', pero si quieres que 'search' sea un parámetro, debes colocar:

```
router.get('/quizes/:search', quizController.search);
```

Aquí al colcoar dos puntos(:) estás diciendo al router: "cuando obtengas esta ruta y tenga un parámetro, ese parámetro lo asignas a una variable llamada search que estará en el objeto params".

Haz ese cambio en tu router y de momento para testear, hazlo en el navegador con el valor que desees:

localhost:[mi_puerto]/quizes/una_palabra_para_buscar

Eso debería hacer que entres a tu controlador.

Para usarlo en el formulario, debes hacer algo diferente. En vez de usar el action del form, mejor haz que en el evento submit del formulario, se haga una petición GET y armas tu url haciendo algo como:

```
const search = getElementById('search').value
const url = `localhost/[mi_puerto/quizes/${search}]`
const req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open('GET', url, true)
req.send()
if (req.status == 200)
  console.log(req.responseText)
```

**Edición**

También puedes dejarlo tal y como lo tienes y sólo modificar tu router:

```
router.get('/quizes', quizController.search);
```

De este modo, cuando hagas

```
/quizes?search=algo
```

Va a entrar a tu controlador. Extraes el parámetro search tal como lo tienes

Comment: Por cierto, tendrías que agregar el atributo ID a tu input search para que obtenga su valor como en el código de ejemplo que puse

Comment: La petición la realiza bien: GET /quizes?search=4 200 8.463 ms - 33699
Para el valor 4 por ejemplo, pero aun con la ruta tal como dices no entra en el módulo.

Comment: La ruta la realiza bien como la tienes o como lo propuse?

Comment: Edité la respuesta